# How to fetch columns of mapped superclass using jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am looking for a similar query Hibernate in Jpa.

In Hibernate I can retrieve all the columns of the mapped superclass using the query:

```java
session.createQuery("from com.app.spring.entity.User", User.class);
```

How can I achieve this using jpa?
I have tried using `SELECT NEW` custom query.

Also if possible I want to get all the entries of child classes too by calling the superclass, not only the common attributes in superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select):

> The select statement in JPQL is exactly the same as for HQL except that JPQL requires a `select_clause`, whereas HQL does not.

So, you can correct your query in the following way:

```java
List<User> users = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select u from com.app.spring.entity.User u", User.class)
.getResultList();
```

Also as it explained in this [section of documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-polymorphism):

> HQL and JPQL queries are inherently polymorphic.
>
> This query names the `User` entity explicitly. However, all subclasses of `User` are also available to the query. So, if the `UserA` and `UserB` entities extend the `User` class, all three types would be available to the entity query, and the query would return instances of all three.

You can even write something like this:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>
{
   @Query("select o from java.lang.Object o")
   List<Object> findAllEntities();
}
```

although this is not very practical from a performance perspective.

Comment: can't this be achieved without using entityManager. Like this @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
Collection<User> findAllActiveUsers();

Comment: Yes, sure you can use `@Query("select u from com.app.spring.entity.User u")`

Comment: but since mapped super class is not an entity it is throwing me error saying it is not an entity

Comment: It looks like just a problem with your mapping, see the updated answer.

Comment: when using inheritance.joined, how to fetch all the rows, for both parent and childs, using jpa query

Comment: If `com.app.spring.entity.User` is your parent class then you can find all your children among the `List<User> users`